# How to pass arguments from the request to controller method with the silex method get()?

Tags: php, controller, arguments, silex

I try Silex Framework, and I may want to pass arguments to a controller method. I have this, like in the doc :

```
$app->get('/projet/{projetName}', 'App\Controller\Projet::single')
->bind('single.projet');
```

How I can pass 'projetName' to 'single' method ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `projetName` as parameter to the method:

```
$app->get('/projet/{projetName}', 'App\Controller\Projet::single')
  ->bind('single.projet');

class Projet
{
  public function single(Application $app, $projetName)
  {
    // do anything with $projetName
  }
}
```

the route variable will be passed to the method.

Comment: Where is passed `$app` to `single` method?